# MVC5 - Proper way to get multiple lists into a view (i.e. Customer Contacts, Customer Locations)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper, poco

I am using MVC5, EF6 DbFirst, AutoMapper. I have 3 tables: Customers, CustomerContacts, CustomerLocations. I set all of my relationships and updated my model from database. Then I created Model (Dto) classes for each of them (i.e. Model.Customer, Model.CustomerContacts, Model.CustomerLocations)

In my controller I have an Action result called Details and in the Details.cshtml I need to display not only basic customer info but also a list of all the customer's contacts and customer's locations.

In my Model.Customer I added the following properties:

```
public List<CustomerContact> Contacts { get; set; }
public List<CustomerLocation> Locations { get; set; }
```

I am trying to figure out how to utilize these properties directly from my Customer object rather than have to pass a Customer and 2 separate lists to my view. Can someone help me with the proper workflow to do something like this in MVC5. It is the only piece I am missing.

Comment: If you have added the above properties to the Customer class, then they are already part of the Customer object. What is the issue in accessing it in the view?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question. Can you add a more complete version of your "main" model (which I assume is the Customer class)?

Comment: I think this is your object-design that a customer object will comprise of list of contact and list of Locations and you replicated the same using OOP, why are you worried now?

Comment: Lets say I use Model.Customer cust = custServer.GetCustomerByID(id) and then do return view(cust) in razor how do I loop through and list my contacts.

Comment: If contacts and locations are properties on the customer object, then they will just be available in the razor model

Comment: Use ViewModel.Have a look at tihs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517239/using-multiple-models-in-a-single-controller/27518525#27518525

Comment: is ViewModel necessary if Contacts and Locations lists are properties of the primary entity. I only want to use ViewModel if I need to display data from completely unrelated tables in the same view. Does this make sense? I think my main problem is the syntax of listing the customer.contacts in razor view.

Comment: @user2272527 It will be in the same way how you are accessing other members of the customer object. Model.Contacts, Model.Locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose You have Customer Object Like below:

```
public string Name{ get; set; }
public string CustLevel{ get; set; }
public List<CustomerContact> Contacts { get; set; }
public List<CustomerLocation> Locations { get; set; }
```

Then in Razor use this model:

```
@Html.LabelFor(t=>t.Name);
@Html.LabelFor(t=>t.CustLevel);

@foreach(var contactlist in Model.Contacts)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(t=>t.ContactNum);
  @Html.LabelFor(t=>t.ContactType);
}
```

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor()`? I think you mean `@Html.DisplayFor()` :)

Answer (score 0):

AS a suggestion I would say just create a model which contains properties like: Name,Contact,Location,etc.

Then In controller create a List type obejct of your Model. Populate it using your Db and pass it into your View.

Then Comes Display Templates. Add a Folder named DisplayTemplates and create a strongly typed view of your model type and pass that list into It . It will iterate automatically and give you the result.