# Sending back a different model from the view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I want to send details of 2 different models to the view so I do this with a view model.

```
namespace Apps.Models
{
public class viewmodel1
{
    public App app { get; set; }
    public List<Colleague> colleague { get; set; }
}
}
```

app being a model that stores a variety of properties about an application, and colleague being a model that stores a variety of properties about colleagues.

Originally I was only passing in app, but I want to be able to display a drop down list of the colleagues first names in this view when creating an app (because the two are linked) so i need to pass in all the current colleagues to get their first names. This part is working.

However, my action result needs to change when the form is submitted to take in this new viewmodel type, and I don't know how to access the properties from the action result. Normally when you bind include there are just properties in the model, but i want to include the properties that are WITHIN the objects the viewmodel has. I don't know how to do this or of i am just doing something wrong.

I would obviously like to retain the validation that is already written for the app properties, but I'm not sure I can do that this way.

Comment: Have you tried it this way, did you encounter a problem or an error, and if so can you edit your question to add any error message you had when you tried to make it work

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517239/using-multiple-models-in-a-single-controller/27518525#27518525

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer to your question without seeing the xaml binding you are trying to use, but you can use bindings that dive into objects.

So if you have an Employee object that is your DataContext (Employee would be your ViewModel although it has no controller logic, so I guess it's just a model here):

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public EmpAddress Address {get; set;}
}

public class EmpAddress
{
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public string Zip {get; set;
}
```

You can do bindings that look like this:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Address.Street}/>
```

Let me know if this isn't what you were after and I'll try to help.