# How to make single view using viewmodel in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have different models Image,Page & PageCategories

```
public class Image
    {
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    }



public class Page
    {
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        public string PageTitle { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int PageCategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual PageCategory PageCategory { get; set; }
    }



public class PageCategory
    {
        public int PageCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; 
        public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    }
```

DBContext Class is

```
 class DemoContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<PageCategory> PageCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        }


    }
```

I am wondering how to get all the model data to the home page using ViewModel.

For Ex.:
How to get image list and Page list in home page from multiple models?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517239/using-multiple-models-in-a-single-controller/27518525#27518525

Comment: Create a view model containing properties `IEnumerable<Image>` and `IEnumerable<Page>`, populate it in the controller and pass it to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke How to populate data in controller after IEnumerable in view models?

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this :

viewModel :

```
    //Create a viewModel with all the properties that you need
    public class ViewModel
        {
            public int ImageId { get; set; }
            public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
            public string ImageURL { get; set; }
            public int PageId { get; set; }
            public string PageTitle { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }
            public int PageCategoryId { get; set; }
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        }
```

Controller :
    ...

```
using (DemoContext db = new DemoContext()){


 List<ImagePageViewModel> viewData = (from p in db.Page
 join pc from db.PageCategory on p.PageCategoryId equals pc.PageCategoryId 
 select new ViewModel(){
 PageTitle=p.PageTitle,
 CategoryName = pc.CategoryName
 //... set every property you want
})
}

return View(viewData );
```

note: I didn't add Image to the query because there is no explicit relation
between Image and the others table so i let you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create another class and define all above three into it. like below

```
public class MyView
{
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public List<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public List<PageCategory> PageCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:-

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyView myView = // Get it using your logic
    return View(myView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally got my answer:

public class ViewModelDemo
    {

```
    public IEnumerable<Image> images { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Pages> pages { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PageCategory> pagecategories { get; set; }

}
```

Then in HomeController

```
    private DemoContext db=new DemoContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    ViewModelDemo vm = new ViewModelDemo();

    vm.images = db.Images.ToList();
    vm.pages=db.Pagess.ToList();
    vm.pagecategories=db.PageCategories.ToList();

    return View(vm);
    }
```