# How do I return two parameters/objects in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is how my controller looks like. I have two tables in one Index. I would like to return objListOfItemsDetails and objListOfItemsDetailsMB. But 1 can only return one object. Thats why i commented 'Return Table Two'. Can anyone show me the right way to do this? thanks

```
       {
            ListOfItems objListOfItemsDetails = new ListOfItems();    //Table One
            objListOfItemsDetails = ARSharedDAL.GetTaskListInfo();   //Table One


            ListOfItems objListOfItemsDetailsMB = new ListOfItems();       //Table Two
            objListOfItemsDetailsMB = ARSharedDAL.GetDashboardInfoMB();    //Table Two


            return View(objListOfItemsDetails);                     //Return Table One
            //return View(objListOfItemsDetailsMB);                 //Return Table Two


        }
```

Comment: Create a view model containing 2 properties `ListOfItems Items1` and `ListOfItems Items2` and return the veiw model.

Comment: where do i create view model? is it in my controller above? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Create a separate folder named say `ViewModels`, then in you Controller, add a using statement to reference it.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517239/using-multiple-models-in-a-single-controller/27518525#27518525