# how to return 2 (or more) objects in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

In my controller code, I need to return two objects to the Details view (details.cshtml)

Below is the Controller code:

```
FinishProductCompleteForm FinishProductCompleteFormDetails = FinishProductCompleteFormDAL.GetFPCompletelDetailsByID(objFinishProductCompleteForm);

FinishProductCompleteForm objRawMatDetails = FinishProductCompleteFormDAL.GetDashboardInfo(FinishProductCompleteFormDetails);

return View(FinishProductCompleteFormDetails);
```

Currently I just can return `FinishProductCompleteFormDetails` only, but I need to return both `FinishProductCompleteFormDetails` and `objRawMatDetails`.

Comment: sir, i don't think that is a similar question..because these 2 objects were in the same class (FinishProductCompleteForm).. @RobertMoskal

Comment: It exactly the same - read the answers in the link. There are multiple ways to do this including creating a view model containing properties for `FinishProductCompleteFormDetails` and `objRawMatDetails`

Comment: You can use viewmodel if you don't want viewmodel return list of objects and in view accept a list of objects of your class. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517239/using-multiple-models-in-a-single-controller/27518525#27518525

Answer (score 0):

you can:

set view model to `IEnumerable<FinishProductCompleteForm>` and return list ob object to your view from action like this:

```
return View(
    new List<FinishProductCompleteForm>()
   { 
       FinishProductCompleteFormDetails, 
       objRawMatDetails 
   });
```

or you can:

create custom model with different fields.

```
public Class CustomModel
{
    public FinishProductCompleteForm FirstProp { get; set; }
    public FinishProductCompleteForm SecondProp { get; set; }
}
```

and in your action return new custom model.

```
return View(
    new CustomModel 
    {
        FirstProp = FinishProductCompleteFormDetails,
        SecondProp = objRawMatDetails
    }
);
```