# How to pass multiple parameters to a view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am passing two list variables in an ActionResult as Below.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<category> cat = _business.ViewAllcat().ToList();
    List<Books> book = _business.ViewAllBooks().ToList();
    return View(book);
}
```

When I run the Code I get the below error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List1[Durgesh_Bhai.Models.category], but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Durgesh_Bhai.Models.Books].

When I am using only one List in Actionresult its working fine.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517239/using-multiple-models-in-a-single-controller/27518525#27518525

Comment: I think problem is with the view can you post your Index  View here

Answer (score 5):

I am also new to mvc but the solution i got was to create a class which will hold all you required objects as data members and pass the object of that class.

I created a class called data and assigned all my objects to the object of this class and sent that object to model.

or you can use view bag

```
Class Data
{
  public List<category> cat {get;set;}
   public List<Books> book {get;set;}
   public Data()
   {
      this.cat = new List<category>();
      this.book = new List<Books>();
   }

}
 public ActionResult Index()
{
    Data d=new Data();

    d.cat = _business.ViewAllcat().ToList();
    d.book = _business.ViewAllBooks().ToList();
    return View(d);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please create a new ViewModel class and store your two lists like so:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.Categories = new List<Category>();
        this.Books = new List<Book>();
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Categories = _business.ViewAllcat().ToList();
    model.Books = _business.ViewAllBooks().ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your View (index.cshtml), declare MyViewModel like so:

```
@model WebApp.Models.MyViewModel

<div>
    your html
</div>
```

The concept we just used is called View Model. Please read more about it here:
[Understanding ViewModel](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/QHQT270712-Understanding-ViewModel-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new object containing both lists.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<category> cat = _business.ViewAllcat().ToList();
    List<Books> book = _business.ViewAllBooks().ToList();
    return View(new CatBooks { Cats = cat, Books = book });
}

public class CatBooks {
    public List<category> Cats { get; set; }
    public List<Books> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ViewModel class (just a .cs class) that contains all of the things you require on the page.

Then the first line of the View, you should use the viewmodel class as your model.

Then populate your model in the controller action, like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<category> cat = _business.ViewAllcat().ToList();
        List<Books> book = _business.ViewAllBooks().ToList();
        return View(new MyViewModel() { Cats = cat, Books = book);
    }
```

Then you'll be able to access everything on the page.